# saving picture from my app

Tags: android

The idea of my app is to capture image from camera then crop specified area from it.

The problem :
      When i save the cropped image in my sd card for the first time to launch the app, it saved properly. but when run my app one more time and take image then crop it. when save it the first image that take and crop at first time appear in the sd card not the current one.

This is my code for save images:

```
public static void save(Activity activity, Bitmap bm, String name) {
    OutputStream outStream = null;

    File externalFilesDir = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File outFile = new File(externalFilesDir, "IDOCR" + File.separator + "Numbers");

    if (!outFile.exists())
        outFile.mkdirs();

    File number = new File(outFile, name + ".PNG");
    //if (number.exists())
    //  number.delete();
    try {
        //outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(number);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

        bm.recycle();
        System.gc();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you are trying to overwrite the previous version of the file, you should first delete the previous one...

You can add:

```
if (!outFile.exists())
    outFile.mkdirs();
else {
    outFile.delete();
    outFile.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same filename for both versions ? Does it work if you change the filename ?

Comment: Yes, i am using the same name.
and it is working if name change.
but i need the same name every time because i am working on it later.

Comment: At least the problem is around that... try with the other line I added. If it still fails, please give more information on the failure.